# Geckofx Handle Document complet

Tags: .net, document, gecko

I need to handle document complet in Geckofx 33 webbrowser 
gecko isbusy function is not working 
StatusText also

```
<i>

web.navigate("http://google.com")

msgbox(web.isbusy) ' this return False '

</i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if 'web' is your geckowebbrowser, then just do:

```
web.DocumentCompleted += web_DocumentCompleted;


  void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
             //do stuff here
        }
```

Also, instead of checking 'isbusy', try having a similar event handler for 'web.navigating'.

Answer (score 0):

`IsBusy` is `True` not immediately after you use `Navigate`.
In my code I wait for some time (1 second) and after that create loop:

```
 Private Sub wait(ByVal interval As Integer)
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    Do While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < interval * 1000
        Application.DoEvents()
        If IBW.CancellationPending = True Then Exit Do
    Loop
    sw.Stop()
End Sub

        Web.Navigate("http://google.com")
        'Now wait for 1 second before checking IsBusy
        wait(1) : Do While IWeb.IsBusy = True : Application.DoEvents() : Loop
```